# an error messege Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, xml

before it was good without error but I dont know when I run it again and it's become error.this is a fregment activity. it close to the main activity when i open it. I already try to create a new xml and rename it but it doesn't work at all.

**This is my ProfileFragment.java**

```
public class ProfilFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public ProfilFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ProfilFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ProfilFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ProfilFragment fragment = new ProfilFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

**this is my fragment_profile.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d2cfcf">


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/man" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Joko Tingkir"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="UangKu: "
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                android:textSize="25dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Rp. 70.000,-"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="25dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="No Rekening: "
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="16dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="34-5563-4564-34"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="15dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="A/N: NarutoU"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Profil Diri"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"></View>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/mailijo" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="uzumaki.naruto@konoha.com"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sex_type" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Pria"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/handphone" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="081290188409"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rumah" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Konoha, Kab. Konohagakure, Negara Api, Indonesia"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/kalender" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="10 Oktober 1997"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></View>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**and suddenly I got this error messege**

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mqa.android.ewasapp, PID: 16111
                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:742)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
                      at com.mqa.android.ewasapp.ProfilFragment.onCreateView(ProfilFragment.java:67)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6337)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
                   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 34776012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 32MB until OOM
                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:624)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:457)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.createFromResourceStream(ResourcesImpl.java:1272)
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:743)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:585)
                      at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:308)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:872)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:141)
```

**this is my build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mqa.android.ewasapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
}
```

**the messenge said that the error in this line**

```
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
```

please help me to fix it

Comment: You have no closing tag for android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: @AlexanderDeych I have it in the end of xml

Comment: you real error is this:
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 34776012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 32MB until OOM

Comment: And this is happening in your imageview where you are setting the background. :)

Comment: Its `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` . Are you using any huge size images as drawable ?

Comment: @Umair but I have no background in my imageview

Comment: @ADM I already change my image but the error still on it

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama i believe then this is vector drawable then ? @drawable/man

Comment: try decreasing the image resolution and see

Comment: @Umair  I compress my image to 16KB but it still error `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 34776012 byte allocation with 16771000 free bytes and 32MB until OOM`

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama see if you are using vector drawable then it might be an version difference issue. otherwise just for test purpose use picassso or glide library to set the imageview and then tell me if it still crashes or not.

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama which android version device/emulator you are testing your project ?

Comment: @Umair version 7.0 nougat

Comment: I try to remove all my image resource from drawable but it still error

Comment: I adding this `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest and it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add two lines in your `style.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

copy and paste whole xml it will work :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <TextView
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#d2cfcf">


        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="130dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/man" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Joko Tingkir"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="25dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                    android:text="UangKu: "
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="25dp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Rp. 70.000,-"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                    android:textSize="25dp" />
                            </LinearLayout>


                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                    android:text="No Rekening: "
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="34-5563-4564-34"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                    android:textSize="15dp" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="A/N: NarutoU"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Profil Diri"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"></View>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/mailijo" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="uzumaki.naruto@konoha.com"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/sex_type" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Pria"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/handphone" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="081290188409"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/rumah" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="Konoha, Kab. Konohagakure, Negara Api, Indonesia"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/kalender" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:text="10 Oktober 1997"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></View>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

see this :-

[image]

When I copied your code into my studio this error will show you can see in below:-

[image]

Comment: do you mind adding some explanation too with your answer, why does it work with adding those two lines ?

Comment: I didn't said it's not working, all I asked was the reason why adding those two lines make it work :)

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working. and I already have that two lines code in my style.xml. maybe I have to change it from the begining?

Comment: because in style.xml don't have theme for Appbar and toolbar that's why it showing error and inflate problem cause of CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: yes but it has. and there is no CoordinatorLayout now. but it's still not working.

Comment: have you solved your query? or still there? if solved please marked with +ve vote.